# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND no encuentra CSS ni JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una pequeña página web para ayudarme a hacer tests en mis estudios.
En el PC funciona correctamente, ahora quiero copiarla al móvil para poder usarla en él.

La página solo tiene tres ficheros, los típicos:

```
index.html
style.css
script.js
```

Bien, he copiado los 3 ficheros dentro de la misma carpeta en mi Android pero al visualizar index.html en el móvil con Chrome no funcionan los botones ni hace nada.

He conectado al móvil al PC con el Debug remoto y parece que no encuentra el fichero para el Js ni los CSS...

En el PC todo funciona bien.
Tengo enlazados estos dos ficheros dentro del html, El CSS dentro del HEAD y el JS justo antes del final del BODY.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Aparecen estos dos mensajes en la consola:

```
style.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
script.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

¿Sabríais qué tengo que hacer para que funcione?

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Haber, hasta donde yo recuerdo, el sistema de ficheros de un Android no funciona de la misma manera que una pc, razón suficiente para que no encuentre los archivos posiblemente.

Comment: Probaste con poner la ruta completa de la carpeta de tu celular?